# Proved by defining the boundary (delta and epsilon)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

I would be happy if anyone could give me a detailed answer. I was unable to express Delta using Epsilon.

My thought was (I will use keyboard keys) |x-a| = |x -(- 7)| = |x + 7| <delta | 3x +20 -1 | = |x + 7 + 2x + 12| < |x + 7| + 2| x + 6| I now have an expression | x + 7 | Which is smaller than Delta, but how do I reduce 2|x+ 6|

\begin{equation*} \lim_{x \rightarrow -7} |3x + 20|=1 \end{equation*}

Comment: Can you please write what did you try and where are you stuck?

Comment: Yes, I did not write because I do not get along so well with writing mathematical expressions as expected, so I will use keyboard keys.
| x-a | = | x - (- 7) | = | x + 7 | <delta
| 3x +20 -1 | = |x + 7 + 2x + 12| < |x + 7| + 2| x + 6|

I now have an expression | x + 7 | Which is smaller than Delta, but how do I reduce 2|x+ 6|

Comment: @roobin Please edit your attempt into the question. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial on MathJax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$. By the reverse triagle inequality we have:

$||3x+20|-1|=||3x+20|-|-1||\leq |(3x+20)-(-1)|=|3x+21|=3|x+7|$

So now let $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{3}$. If $|x-(-7)|=|x+7|<\delta$ then we get:

$||3x+20|-1|\leq 3|x+7|< 3\delta=3\frac{\epsilon}{3}=\epsilon$